# Exporting a timeslice from a Netcdf-Rasterlayer as tif-rasterlayer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.4, netcdf

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 (advanced licence) I downloaded a NetCDF-File from here: http://eca.knmi.nl/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php (the 0.25 grid with the years 1995-2016). It consists of temperature-data over time (in days).

I read it into ArcGIS as a NetCDF-Rasterlayer, and now I'm trying to export data of a single time-slice as a tif-rasterlayer. I did not get the hang on Mosaic Datasets, so my plan is to make a spatial analysis on the exported tif-rasterlayer, relating it to landuse (also in a tif-rasterlayer), and later aggregating it to NUTS3-Level). If I keep track what happens to which rasters I can later export other time-slices as tables and relate the spatial analysis to them.

The export-function (Data->Export) works in principle, but the raster looses it's attribute table, and without that I can't keep track which cell relates to which.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get that working?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool "Copy Raster" that will export the current timeslice.

See [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252279/adding-netcdf-file-to-mosaic-dataset-in-arcgis-desktop#comment397818_252279) on [Adding NetCDF-File to Mosaic Dataset in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252279/adding-netcdf-file-to-mosaic-dataset-in-arcgis-desktop#) .